# Does confluent kafka (cp-kafka) support Log4j RollingFileAppender with Time/Size Based Triggering Policy & Rollover Strategy? Doesn't seem to work

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, log4j

I am using the [Confluent Community](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cp-kafka/confluentinc/cp-kafka/7.0.2/images/sha256-dd2b682e17cd606f26c2232b048a171d59a976db61c33e7a6c7da7ad08ff66e3?context=explore) Docker Image for Apache Kafka & trying to have the Kafka logs rolled over daily with a Time & Size Based Triggering Policy & Rollover Strategy.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/development.html#log-to-external-volumes), I have extended the image & set it up with a Log4j configuration via properties.

However i see that only basic configuration of `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` **without any daily rolling or policies** appears to work (the commented out config settings in the property file below).

The examples on the docs also appears to use only the very old Log4j1.x `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender` which as we know (and as per 1.x [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)) should not even be used. I am not even sure if Kafka packaged `apache-log4j-extras` along with log4j1.x earlier.

Below are the Dockerfile & log4j properties i am using. Any of you guys had any luck with it? Am i doing something incorrectly in the below?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.2
COPY log4j.properties.template /etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template
```

log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger={{ env["KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL"] | default('INFO') }}, stdout, rollingFile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

#log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server.log
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.filePattern=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=5KB
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=15
#log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true

log4j.appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
log4j.appender.rolling.name=rollingFile
# Below is the default..just making explicit.
log4j.appender.rolling.append=true
log4j.appender.rolling.fileName=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server1.log
log4j.appender.rolling.filePattern=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
# Below is the default..just making explicit.
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.interval=1
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.size.size=20MB
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
# Delete all files older than 15 days
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type=Delete
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath=/var/log/kafka/
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type=IfLastModified
log4j.appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age=15d


{% set loggers = {
  'kafka': 'INFO',
  'kafka.network.RequestChannel$': 'WARN',
  'kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler': 'DEBUG',
  'kafka.request.logger': 'WARN',
  'kafka.controller': 'TRACE',
  'kafka.log.LogCleaner': 'INFO',
  'state.change.logger': 'TRACE',
  'kafka.authorizer.logger': 'WARN'
  } -%}


{% if env['KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS'] %}
{% set loggers = parse_log4j_loggers(env['KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS'], loggers) %}
{% endif %}

{% for logger,loglevel in loggers.items() %}
log4j.logger.{{logger}}={{loglevel}}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

UPDATE (Aug 3, 2022):

Here is the official [link](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/development.html#log-to-external-volumes) from Confluent that still points to the usage of very old `DailyRollingFileAppender`. Perhaps Confluent still recommends using this i guess even though Log4j recommends against using it [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

UPDATE (Aug 11, 2022):

I even posted this in the confluent community [forum](https://forum.confluent.io/t/does-confluent-kafka-cp-kafka-support-log4j-rollingfileappender-with-time-size-based-triggering-policy-rollover-strategy-doesnt-seem-to-work/5686) few days back & will update here in case someone knows/answers.

Thanks

Comment: What i have tried above is following the examples in the section "Configuration with Properties" in the Log4j [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)

Comment: Note that the basic option of a fixed window rolling based on index along with file size already works as mentioned in the above commented section of the properties at the top, its the daily rolling with time & size based triggering plus deletion that doesn't work following the examples mentioned in the log4j2 docs..

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it works like a champ. You can even update the ConversionPattern with any specific format you are after.

```
# DEFAULT: console appender only
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, ROLLINGFILE


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=10
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server.%i.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10485760
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.storage=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.config=ERROR
```

Comment: Thank you @ChristDist. This looks similar to the older config method (the commented out version). 
Fixed Window rolling with file size already works with my commented out version aswell, although yours is better, but the problem is with the daily rolling with file size (using TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy & SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy) along with deletion of old files with a deletion strategy as i tried in my above case.

Comment: What i have tried is following the examples in the section "Configuration with Properties" in the Log4j [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)